# windows - chrome/firefox can play sound but media players cannot

Tags: windows, audio, media-player

On my Windows 7 Laptop, sound recently stopped working in WMP/VLC/MPC/iTunes/QuicMPCkTime, however, sound continues to work in chrome, firefox and IE. dxdiag reports no errors.

My sound card is a Realtek HDA card. (However, it was working a month ago).

- **dxdiag gives no errors**
- MPC-HC says it's playing, but doesn't actually play
- Windows Media Player says "Windows Media Player encountered a problem while playing the file."
- VLC says it's playing, but consulting the "messages" area gives this: http://pastebin.com/qL44n92w
- QuickTime says it's playing, but doesn't.
- iTunes refuses to play

Whereas, if I open the same media file in chrome or firefox, it plays perfectly.

Just to clarify, no media players show up in Sound Settings *at all*. I can't unmute/mute them because they're *not there*.

Comment: Have a look at your sound-settings. maybe you have muted the players per accident.

Comment: @Chris, the players don't actually show up in sound settings (but firefox and chrome do)

Comment: So I think there is the problem.

Comment: how is that the problem? All that tells me is that whatever it's trying to do is failing before it shows up in the sound settings. I don't know what's going wrong, or how to fix it.

Comment: any errors in event log?  
did you verify system files  (sfc /scannow)? 
is it possible to system restore from an earlier date?

Comment: @Hefewe1zen - verified system files (nothing wrong there), reinstalled DirectX, no event log errors - and it still happens. (It's definitely a directx bug, switching VLC to WaveOut audio output works.)